# How Include the font family (SFUIDisplay-Regular) in angular project?

Tags: css, angular, sass, font-face

we are trying to include the font-family SFUIDisplay-Regular we generate all the file formate like .eot,.otf, .svg, .ttf, .woff 
these all file are import in my SCSS file but it's not work...

scss code are given below.

```
 @import "./assets/fonts/SF_font/styles.css";

 @font-face {
      font-family: 'SFUIDisplay-Regular' !important;
      src: url('./assets/fonts/SF_font/SFUIDisplay-Regular.ttf') format('embedded-opentype');
      font-weight: normal;
      font-style: normal;
    }

body{
        font-family: $fontFamily;
          // letter-spacing: -1px;
          background: $backgroundgray;
          font-size: 14px;
          color: $textcolor;
          line-height: 16px;
            padding-bottom:15px;
    }
```

Comment: 1) What is the value of  `$fontFamily` variable? 2) For the web it's enough to load only .woff file. 3) There is no need to write `!important` inside `@font-face` rule. 4) For .ttf file use `format('truetype')`. 5) What is inside `./assets/fonts/SF_font/styles.css` file? | You can read about web fonts here https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/

Comment: $fontFamily : 'SFUIDisplay-Regular';